# Videolightbox jQuery only can be fired once on page

Tags: jquery, html, firebug, lightbox

at the site I'm working on [euroworker.no](http://www.euroworker.no), we have a [videolightbox](http://videolightbox.com/) (click "se video") that shows a youtube video. Thing is, it can only be called once, in any browser.

After this is called also, [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) racks up a whole lot of errors!

I've looked through and can't seem to identify why it will only fire once.

Here's [the Videolightbox code](http://jsfiddle.net/5bzFa/).

Can anyone help out as to why it will only fire once? And also why it would rack up all those errors after?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not used videolightbox, but I have used ShadowBox and that can fire as many times as you want on a page. The difficulty with the videolightbox one is that it's generating all the code from a desktop application so you dont know how it would be affecting the backend, if this code is conflicting with something you have written manually it could be nigh on impossible to debug.

With Shadowbox it only needs a small code injection and installing some libraries to your server and your good to go (you also have the advantage of knowing that all code written is yours):

[ShadowBox Usage](http://shadowbox-js.com/usage.html)